# Is it possible to 'dump' a running process and restore/continue it on another PC?

Tags: debugging, minidump

We have a problem at a customer which is not reproducible (some data is shown incorrectly).  The customer itself has the problem several times per day, but we can't reproduce the problem in house.

We could use remote debugging to investigate the running process once the customer has the problem, but this requires a developer PC to connect to the customer PC via lots of VPN software.  In practice, this is almost impossible since the customer does not want us to connect directly to the server running the application (often there is also a Remote Desktop or Citrix system involved).

I know you can make a MiniDump of a running process to investigate it in a debugger, but then you cannot continue the process to see what's is really going on.

Is there a possiblity to make a dump of the process, copy the dump to the developers PC, and continue the process on the developers PC?
Application is a native unmanaged C++ application.

Of course, all logic related to database connections, network connections, files, ... would be unavailable, but in this case I am mainly interested in the internal logic.

If this is not possible, is this generally possible using a virtual machine instead?